# React props destructuring after updates stopped working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really confused, I am used to to create stateless components with props destructuring. After upgrading to the latest version of React and Eslint and Webpack. Suddenly I am getting the following error:

```
./src/components/Blog/Post.js
  Line 4:  'title' is missing in props validation        react/prop-types
  Line 4:  'description' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
```

Why did this stop working?

I have also wrapped the props with a check.. and still getting the same error.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Post = props => {
    const { title, description } = props;
    return (
        <article>
            <header>
                {title && <h2>{props}</h2>}
                {description && <p>{description}</p>}
            </header>
        </article>
    );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are warnings to remind you to add [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// ...

// This will remove warnings.
Post.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  description: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: Is this really important, and is it best practice to use this in any component?

Comment: @Galanthus Yes best practices to document your prop types in a component either statefull/stateless.  **As your app grows, you can catch a lot of bugs with typechecking. For some applications, you can use JavaScript extensions like Flow or TypeScript to typecheck your whole application. But even if you don’t use those, React has some built-in typechecking abilities.**

Comment: thank you, my friend, for the advice. Will be using these all the time. So basically, it will always check if there is a prop available correct?

Comment: @Galanthus Yes that, when you say for example `description: PropTypes.string.required`, and when you mention `description: PropTypes.string` it checks the type of the value when it is not `undefined` .